# How to join on condition count

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables. First one has id with versions:

```
Fid start_dt                  end_dt                 text
1  2021-09-01 00:00:00     2021-10-09 23:59:59      first_row 
1  2021-10-10 00:00:00     2999-12-12 23:59:59      second_row
2  2021-10-02 00:00:00     2999-12-12 23:59:59      third_row   
3  2021-09-05 00:00:00     2021-09-06 23:59:59      fourth_row
3  2021-09-07 00:00:00     2999-12-12 23:59:59      fifth_row
```

And second table with calls:

```
id  dt                    Fid
1  2021-09-01 05:00:00    1
2  2021-10-01 18:00:00    2
3  2021-10-11 05:00:00    1
4  2021-10-01 16:50:00    2
```

The desired result is

```
id   text
1    first_row
2    third_row
3    second_row
4    third_row
```

I want this script for rows in t1 which have several versions

```
select id,text
from t2
left join t1 on t1.Fid = t2.Fid and t2.dt between t1.start_dt and t1.end_dt
```

And this script for rows in t1 which have one version

```
select id,text
from t2
left join t1 on t1.Fid = t2.Fid and t2.dt between t1.start_dt and t1.end_dt
```

How to do this? I thought about setting to the row flag depending on the number of versions, but maybe there is an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do ([Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cHqGW8zQCANBbaJ1xLgCNa/0))

```
with x as (select fid,count(*) as qty from tb1 group by fid)
select tb2.id, tb1.text 
from tb2 join tb1 on tb2.fid = tb1.fid and tb2.dt between tb1.start_dt and end_dt
join x on tb2.fid = x.fid and x.qty > 1

union

select tb2.id, tb1.text 
from tb2 join tb1 on tb2.fid = tb1.fid
join x on tb2.fid = x.fid and x.qty = 1
order by id;
```